# HTAccess Rewrite Rules with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, get

I am building a page that should receive get parameters to determine what content to display. In order to create better-looking URLs, I am using htaccess to allow the urls to appear as following:

`http://www.domain.com/elections/candidate-speech/candidate-name/`

and redirect to the page

`http://www.domain.com/elections/candidate-speech.php?name=candidate-name`

I have done this before successfully and was re-using rules that I wrote for a different page but with a similar desired structure. The rule I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on Rewriting Engine

RewriteRule  ^candidate-speech/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    candidate-speech.php?name=$1
```

If i directly load the intended URL (`http://www.domain.com/elections/candidate-speech.php?name=candidate-name`) with a candidate's name, I get the page displayed as intended. When I attempt to use the shortened version, however, I get the correct page but nothing is provided in `$_GET`.

The .htaccess file is stored in the elections directory, as is the relevant .php file, which is the same setup I used in the past where this rule was successful. I am fairly new to htaccess, which is why I am falling back on my previous success with it. I have restarted the server, cleared my cache, et al. to no avail. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any other rules in `election/.htaccess`? You should add a `[L]` flag to the end of the `candidate-speech.php` rule (which looks correct otherwise). Some browsers are really aggressive about caching redirects, despite having cleared it. I'd also try this out in a different browser or a private browsing window.

Comment: And if you didn't already, be sure to `var_dump($_GET);` in there to verify exactly what (or indeed nothing at all) is in `$_GET`.

Comment: I did the var_dump on $_GET first thing when the page output all the placeholder information.

The only other rule is a duplicate of the posted rule but that uses candidate-speech-wk instead of candidate-speech for both the input and output urls (I like to have a work file I can use if something goes wrong while it's live)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /elections/

RewriteRule ^candidate-speech/([\w-]+)/?$ candidate-speech.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Disabling `MultiViews` option is important here since your `.php` file name is same as the starting component `candidate-speech/`.

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.